# What is the difference between 'In' and 'During'?

Tags: word-choice

How different are the following two sentences:

```
I am not allowed to sleep during the day.
I am not allowed to sleep in the day.
```

Comment: The first treats 'day' as a continuum; the second as a discrete unit. Eventually, they mean practically the same. HTH.

Comment: HTH means "Hope that helps." or "Happy to help."

Answer (score 2):

Graphically "in" can be represented with a point on a section of a line, standing for a period of time.

"during" belongs to the word family duration (in German there is still the verb dauern). "during" could be represented graphically by a section of a line for time period and a second parallel line covering all of the period of time.